# While update the submodule package for pico c/c++ sdk getting fatal errors on window

Tags: git, raspberry-pi-pico

Here I have provide CLI error details :

```
C:\Users\Soumen Nayak>cd ..

C:\Users>cd ..

C:\>cd pico

C:\pico>cd pico-sdk

C:\pico\pico-sdk>cd pico-sdk

C:\pico\pico-sdk\pico-sdk>git submodule update --init
Cloning into 'C:/pico/pico-sdk/pico-sdk/lib/btstack'...
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 7498 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack.git' into 
submodule path 'C:/pico/pico-sdk/pico-sdk/lib/btstack' failed
Failed to clone 'lib/btstack'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/pico/pico-sdk/pico-sdk/lib/mbedtls'...

C:\pico\pico-sdk\pico-sdk>git submodule sync
Synchronizing submodule url for 'lib/btstack'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'lib/cyw43-driver'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'lib/lwip'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'lib/mbedtls'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'lib/tinyusb'

C:\pico\pico-sdk\pico-sdk>git pull
Already up to date.

C:\pico\pico-sdk\pico-sdk>git pull/submodule update
git: 'pull/submodule' is not a git command. See 'git --help'
```

I am trying to install pico c/c++ sdk in my system but getting fatal error please provide some solution

Thanks